# Default credentials appearing out of nowhere in symfony 3 login form

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use the fosuserbundle for handle user login in a symfony 3 project. My loginAction looks like this

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) 
    {
      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fusion_design_blog_homepage'));
    }

    $session = $request->getSession();

    if ($request->attributes->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR))
    {
      $error = $request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } 
    else
    {
      $error = $session->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
      $session->remove(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('FusionDesignUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
      'last_username' => $session->get(Security::LAST_USERNAME),
      'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

and the related twig template is the following

```
<div id="login">
    <form action="{{ path('fos_user_security_check') }}" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="loginField" placeholder="username"/>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="loginField" placeholder="password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="log in" id="loginButton"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, it all works fine. Login, logout, errors and the rest is all doing what it's supposed to do, except for one small exception.

If I haven't attempted (and gotten a bad credential error) to fill in the credentials during this session yet, the form username and password field will have default values, the default value of username being "root."

I have tried to locate where this "root" is coming from but it doesn't matter what I do, "root" is always there, even if it's nowhere to be found in the source html. I'm honestly at a loss, does anyone has an idea?

**Edit**

Turns out it was the browser messing with the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to do this in private navigation. It looks like your browser is filling the field with old values.